# Launching a method that is inside a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having trouble killing PhantomJS.

I insert this

```
Thread initThread;
initThread = new Thread()
{


    public void run()
        {
            WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            driverList.add(driver);
        }

};
initThreadList.add(initThread);
```

into a for loop (this loops runs 10 times) and then I insert the newly created thread inside a Thread List, afterwards I instantiate every thread at the same time with an ExecutorService.

After doing this, I run another ExecutorService (Like the first one, so with a thread and a run method) that uses the fresh PhantomJS Drivers, at the end of the run method I'd like to kill the used PJS Driver.

Now, using `initThreadList.interrupt()` (at the end of the run method), does NOT work, and leaves the processes running (I can see that from the task manager), and, because this project that I am doing should support 100+ threads (every thread with PhantomJS), this is not a nice situation (every 10 threads the program wastes ~1gb of ram, and that ram does not get emptied at all).

I thought of using a custom 'run' method called ‘kill’ like this:

```
Thread initThread;
initThread = new Thread()
{


    public void run()
        {
            WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            driverList.add(driver);
        }
    public void kill()
    {
        //handle the killing of the driver here
    }

};
```

but obviously, when trying to do `initThreadList.get(x).kill()` eclipse tells me that `kill()` does not exist.

What can I do?

Comment: You could try creating a class that extends `Thread` and implement the kill method there. Your `driverList` should be a list of these classes, and add those to the list. Then the kill method should be accessible. I haven't worked with PhantomJS though, so it may handle threading differently.

Comment: @coolioasjulio Will try, and update the post ASAP. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't create a method inside the `Thread` object itself, you can create a new class that implements `Runnable`, containing your `kill` method:

```
public class DriverThread implements Runnable {
    private List<WebDriver> driverList;

    public DriverThread(List<WebDriver> driverList) {
        this.driverList = driverList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driverList.add(driver);
    }

    public void kill() {
        // Kill your driver here!
    }
}
```

Now, you can create your thread(s) similarly to how you were previously:

```
DriverThread driverThread = new DriverThread(driverList);

Thread initThread = new Thread(driverThread);

initThreadList.add(initThread);
```

When you want to kill a certain `DriverThread`'s `WebDriver`, you can use the following:

```
driverThread.kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to kill the `WebDriver`? From what I understand, you start the WebDriver in the thread, and some time later you want to kill it. If that's the case, then you should actually use the `interrupt()` method of the thread. It doesn't kill the thread for you, it sets a flag, and you must kill it yourself.

For example, after you init the `WebDriver` and add it to the driverlist, put this in the end of the `run()` method:

```
while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterrupedException e) {
        break;
    }
}
driver.quit(); // Or however you kill the driver
```

This code repeatedly sleeps, checking to see if the thread is interrupted, and won't pass the while loop until then. Then, it invokes the quit method. (or whatever you do to kill the WebDriver)

This is of course assuming that the thread isn't doing anything else, since it needs to repeatedly poll for the thread interrupt.

Comment: This could be a solution, but how efficient is it? I might need 300/400+ threads at some point, and sleeping does not seem to be the most efficient way to do it here.